# Fixing Memory Leaks in Wordpress (HHVM)

Tags: php

My server is running HHVM.

Everything is working almost fine, except on thing. Because of memory leaks the Translation Cache gets filled up, and once it is almost full the HHVM can not render the pages anymore so every user only would see a blank page instead of the article.

To prvent this from happening it is necessary that all create_function calls get replaced by anonymous functions.
See (for more info): https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4250#issuecomment-88941383
and the docs of hhvm which also say to use anonymous functions: http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.create-function.php

So my question now is how do I replace the create function calls which are made in the translation.php and the po.php with anonymous functions?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

If HHVM has bugs with core PHP functionality then it is not ready to be used for production sites.

Answer (score 0):

In `pomo/po.php`:

```
# pomo/po.php
# 168:            $res = implode("\n", array_map(create_function('$x', "return $php_with.\$x;"), $lines));
# 256:            $is_final = create_function('$context', 'return $context == "msgstr" || $context == "msgstr_plural";');
# 349:            if (array() == array_filter($entry->translations, create_function('$t', 'return $t || "0" === $t;'))) {

            $res = implode( "\n", array_map( function( $x ) {
                return $php_with.\$x;
            }, $lines ) );

            $is_final = function( $context ) {
                return $context == "msgstr" || $context == "msgstr_plural";
            }

            if (array() == array_filter($entry->translations, function($t) { return $t || "0" === $t; } ) ) {
```

However, in `pomo/translations.php`, the line is

```
pomo/translations.php
208: return create_function('$n', $func_body);
```

Since $func_body is a variable, we have to take a closer look at the code:

```
function make_plural_form_function($nplurals, $expression) {
    $expression = str_replace('n', '$n', $expression);
    $func_body = "
        \$index = (int)($expression);
        return (\$index < $nplurals)? \$index : $nplurals - 1;";
    return create_function('$n', $func_body);
}
```

We can try to use PHP's `use` keyword (haven't tested this, no promises it works):

```
function make_plural_form_function($nplurals, $expression) {
    $expression = str_replace('n', '$n', $expression);
    return function( $n ) use ( $expression, $nplurals ) {
        $index = (int)($expression);
        return ($index < $nplurals) ? $index : $nplurals - 1;
    } 
}
```

Having said all of this, unless you absolutely **must** use HHVM, don't. This is a large issue, and even fixing these calls once means that you'll have to do it over and over each time you reinstall or upgrade WordPress.

**EDIT: BIG WARNING HERE. WHAT I AM SUGGESTING IS A MODIFICATION TO WORDPRESS CORE. THIS SHOULD NEVER BE AN OPTION, ESPECIALLY IN A PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT, UNLESS YOU ARE WILLING TO TAKE ON THE LONG-TERM MAINTENANCE OF A HACK TO THE CORE. DO NOT DO THIS**

Comment: changing core files should never be an option in an answer here....

Comment: @MarkKaplun I completely agree, however OP may be in a situation where they can't use anything other than HHVM. In such a case, this may be the only option for preventing these memory issues since HHVM doesn't play nice with `create_function`. Edit: added a warning to my answer

Comment: cool with the edit. But if the OP can use only HHVM, then he should have simply said he works for facebook and then yeh, they have the man power to maintain a fork of wordpress :)